# Error tf2_ros StaticTransformBroadcaster API in Python

Tags: ros, python, tf2-ros, rospy, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:
In an attempt to get around losing the ability to pub latch transforms in the API in python I  have tried doing the following which does not seem to work. Anyone have a way to do this? And in general does anyone know why there is no StaticTransformBroadcaster.py in Indigo why was this not implemented?

```
def publishLatchTransforms(self):
     self.pub_tf = rospy.Publisher("/tf_static", TFMessage , queue_size=1)
    
     # Send static link transforms
     msg = TransformStamped()

     msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
     msg.transform.rotation.x =  0.0
     msg.transform.rotation.y =  0.0
     msg.transform.rotation.z =  0.0
     msg.transform.rotation.w =  1 
     msg.header.frame_id = "base_footprint"   
     msg.transform.translation.x = 0.
      msg.transform.translation.y = 0.0
     msg.transform.translation.z = 0.1
     msg.child_frame_id = "base_link"
     self.pub_tf.publish([msg])
```

How do you call static transform broadcaster in Python?
I can do this in cpp but I can not seem to get this to work in python.

thanks.

```
#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster .h>

ok in cpp but

from tf2_ros import static_transform_broadcaster

fails in python unable to find import
   Static_Transform_Broadcaster()  fails invalid gobal
```

OR

How can I send a transform to the tf/static topic using  sendTransform as a work around.
Rather then using the static transform broadcaster in the  launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203327/error-tf2_ros-statictransformbroadcaster-api-in-python/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You code looks okay. Did you try adding `latch=true` to your `rospy.Publisher()`? If that doesn't work, maybe this is the problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/84336/latchtrue-in-rospypublisher-appears-to-have-no-effect/ . Try adding a `sleep` between creating the publisher and sending the msg.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-02-24**:
Putting a sleep between did not work. The latch worked but it only transmits the last transform on the topic so if I send two the first is ignored even if I use separate publishers. Would sending an array work?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-02-24**:
So publishing array with latch = yes works fine. thanks